# populating input field with row data when row is clicked on

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

How can i populate form inputs with the row data of a row that is clicked on? (using AG GRID and vanilla JS)

Example code would be appreciated

```
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {field: "make", sortable: true, filter: true},
        {field: "model", sortable: true, filter: true},
        {field: "price", sortable: true, filter: true}
    ],
    rowData: [
        {make: "VW", model: "Jetta", price: "$25,000"},
        {make: "Honda", model: "Odyssey", price: "$35,000"},
        {make: "Audi", model: "Q2", price: "$45,000"}
    ],
    animateRows: true,
    onCellClicked: params => {
        let dataMake = params.data.make;
        console.log(dataMake);
        const fillInput = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const input1 = document.querySelector("#input1").value
            console.log(input1);
            input1 = "dataMake"
        }
        
    }
};

new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions)
fetch("https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    gridOptions.api.setRowData(data)
});
```

Comment: Please specify the details of your form. Don't make people guess what the variable/field/id names are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you know how to set values in your form, and that you're just asking how to get the data from the grid.

So, if I understand correctly, you're asking about filling in multiple form fields, corresponding to multiple cells in grid row, when the row is clicked.

Your code looks correct except that you are using the `onCellClicked` property where you should be using `onRowClicked`.

With `onCellClicked` the param to the callback is the data backing the cell that was clicked, while with `onRowClicked` the param is the object backing the entire row.